# Replace dom content before it gets rendered for SEO purposes

Tags: javascript, dom, seo

We're working on a product that changes content on a given web page. Now, what we'd like to do, is have this changed content crawled by Google. The content replacement is triggered by different URLs (either sub domain, html5 pushstate or hashbang^1).

What happens right now is that a user (or a bot) sees the content momentarily (usually for just a fraction of a second), before it gets replaced.

Is it possible to hack the rendering of the browser to change the content before it gets rendered? Would this have a positive effect on Google crawling? Or, does anyone have a better idea besides pushing new pages with pushState?

1 Shoot me #!?$?. But nobody uses it, so it's great for us since we don't control the site the script is running on.

**EDIT:**

HTML snapshots seem to be a possible solution here, proxying if search engine, evaluating original, sending back content https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/html-snapshot

Comment: google bots can't render javascript and they won't see the new text at all

Comment: They execute *some* javascript. And I get it's problematic, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: This is one of the worst things for SEO you can possibly do. It even has a name - cloaking

Comment: Good point! But don't judge just yet; clients control the content that gets replaced. They want to have it indexed.

Comment: Technically, it's also _not_ cloaking. The content resides on a different url.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much control you have over the browser's rendering process.

But if you can proxy all URLs on the original site that contain `_escaped_fragment_` in the querystring to your own site, then you can fetch the page on your server, apply the changes server-side, and serve the modified page to Google, who should then index it correctly.

Comment: Upvoting this, came across it through google's documents as well, thanks! Still very much interested if there's still a js only hack (saving time and resources :))

Answer (score 0):

Keep using `pushState`, but when the URL is visited directly: generate the initial view of the page using server side logic instead of client side logic.

This will sort out both the problems of flashing the wrong content to clients with JavaScript and not showing the right content at all to clients without JavaScript.